# HTML SelectBox view Salesforce Object data

Tags: html, salesforce, apex, visualforce

I am new to SalesForce and am using HTML for VisualForce pages, since it's more flexible to design pages than Apex.

Now I have been stuck at inputting SalesForce Object Data into HTML SelectBox with id "Lop".

This is my VisualForce code, this is where I am using HTML and CSS for design:

```
<apex:page docType="html-5.0" controller="ThemMoiController">
    <!-- CSS -->
    <style>
        table{
            border:1px solid black;
        }
        td{
            text-align: middle
        }
        #NgaySinh, #ThemMoi{
            box-sizing: border-box;
            min-width: 10px;
            max-width: 100%;
            width: 100%;
        }
    </style>
    
    <!-- HTML -->
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <u>Quay lại</u>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr/>
        <tr>
            <td/>
            <td>Họ</td>
            <td>
                <input id="Ho" type="text" value="{!hoVal}"/>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td/>
            <td>Tên</td>
            <td>
                <input id="Ten" type="text" value="{!tenVal}"/>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td/>
            <td>Giới tính</td>
            <td>
                <input id="GioiTinh" type="checkbox" value="{!gioitinhVal}"/>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td/>
            <td>Ngày sinh</td>
            <td>
                <input id="NgaySinh" type="date" value="{!ngaysinhVal}"/>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td/>
            <td>Điểm 1</td>
            <td>
                <input id="Diem1" type="text" value="{!diem1Val}"/>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td/>
            <td>Điểm 2</td>
            <td>
                <input id="Diem2" type="text" value="{!diem2Val}"/>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td/>
            <td>Điểm 3</td>
            <td>
                <input id="Diem3" type="text" value="{!diem3Val}"/>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td/>
            <td>Lớp</td>
            <td>
                <select id="Lop"/>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr/><tr/>
        <tr>
            <td/><td/>
            <td>
                <button id="ThemMoi" type="button">Thêm mới</button>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</apex:page>
```

and this is my Controller Apex code:

```
public class ThemMoiController {
    public string hoVal { get; set; }
    public string tenVal { get; set; }
    public boolean gioitinhVal { get; set; }
    public date ngaysinhVal { get; set; }
    public double diem1Val { get; set; }
    public double diem2Val { get; set; }
    public double diem3Val { get; set; }
    
    public void doInsert(){
        HOCSINH__c hs = new HOCSINH__c();
        hs.HO__c = hoVal;
    }
}
```

Really appreciate for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can create a variable which will be a list of lop sobject.

then in constructor fetch all the records of lop object that you want to show in select dropdown list using soql query and assign the result of soql query to above mentioned variable which is list of lop sobject.

then create getter method as mentioned below that will return list of selectOption class. put the dropdown values in the list of selectOption variable from the list of lop variable.

```
public List<SelectOption> getItems() {
     List<SelectOption> options = new List<SelectOption>();
     options.add(new SelectOption('US','US'));
     options.add(new SelectOption('CANADA','Canada'));
     options.add(new SelectOption('MEXICO','Mexico'));
     return options;
 }
```

use the below code to implement select functionality on VF Page.

```
<apex:form>
        <apex:selectList value="{!variableToStoreSelectedValue}" multiselect="true">
            <apex:selectOptions value="{!items}"/>
        </apex:selectList><p/>
</apex:form>
```

go to the doc link for more details : https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.234.0.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_selectList.htm

Answer (score 0):

-> create new sobject variable with getter setter and initialize this variable in the constructor.

-> then use this sobject variable in vf to input the field value   from user.

-> update the doInsert method to create the new record.

Apex Controller:

```
public class ThemMoiController {
    public string hoVal { get; set; }
    public string tenVal { get; set; }
    public boolean gioitinhVal { get; set; }
    public date ngaysinhVal { get; set; }
    public double diem1Val { get; set; }
    public double diem2Val { get; set; }
    public double diem3Val { get; set; }

    public HOCSINH__c hs { get; set; }
    
    public ThemMoiController(){
        hs = new HOCSINH__c();
    }

    public void doInsert(){
        insert hs;
        system.debug('---->'+hs);
    }
}
```

VF Page:

```
    <apex:page docType="html-5.0" controller="ThemMoiController">
        <!-- CSS -->
        <style>
            table{
                border:1px solid black;
            }
            td{
                text-align: middle
            }
            #NgaySinh, #ThemMoi{
                box-sizing: border-box;
                min-width: 10px;
                max-width: 100%;
                width: 100%;
            }
        </style>
        <apex:form>
        <!-- HTML -->
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <u>Quay lại</u>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>name</td>
                <td>
                    <apex:inputField value="{!hs.name}"/>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Họ</td>
                <td>
                    <apex:inputField id="Ho" value="{!hs.HO__c}"/>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                  
                    <apex:commandButton action="{!doInsert}" value="Thêm mới" />
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        </apex:form>
    </apex:page>
```

-> when we click on 'Thêm mới' button a new record will get created in the HOCSINH__c object.

Comment: Thank you, but I need is to display the LOP object to my selectbox. Cuz as you can see, there is a select tag before the Themmoi button. That is selectbox and I want it to display value from the LOP object.

Comment: this comment box is not allowing characters more than 400 so i have posted new answer.